# Rendering data from a model to another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to ROR. I'm implementing a website that create a permit then after that will redirect the user to an invoice page. I have a user model, invoice model and permit model which they have association with each other below:

invoice.rb

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :receipt
  belongs_to :permit
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :permits
  has_many :visitor_permits
  has_many :healthreports
  has_secure_password
end
```

permit.rb

```
class Permit < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :invoice
end
```

What I going to do is the user fill in all the details when they applying for permits and the information will save into the permit model. After that, user will be redirect to invoice page which render all the data which just filled from the user in the permit application page and extract it from permit model and display on the invoice page which after that will be save again into the invoice page. I have no idea on how to start it. Any idea on how to do it?

I have permit and invoice controller. If you guys need any more information or my code feel free to tell me. Thanks!

What I have tried is creating a variable linked with the permits model in my invoice controller NEW action so I can use it to render the data from Permit model and then save it to invoice model.

```
class InvoiceController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @permits = Permit.find(params[:id])
    @invoice = Invoice.new
  end

  def create
    #@current_user = User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
    @invoice = current_user.visitor_permits.invoices.build(invoice_params)
    if @invoice.save

    else

    end
  end

  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_invoice
    @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def invoice_params
    params.require(:invoice).permit(:vehicle_type, :name, :department, :carplate, :duration, :permitstart, :permitend, :price, :time)
  end
end
```

But I keep getting the error

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in InvoiceController#new
Couldn't find Permit with 'id'=
```

which point to the NEW action.

```
@permits = Permit.find(params[:id])
```

This is my permits_controller.rb which will redirect user in the CREATE action once the button pressed

```
class PermitsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_permit, only: [:destroy]
  def index
    @permits = Permit.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
  end

  def new
    @permits = Permit.new
  end

  def create
    @permits = current_user.permits.build(permit_params)
    if @permits.save
      redirect_to createinvoice_path(@permits)

    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end


  def destroy
    Permit.destroy_all(user_id: current_user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Permit was successfully canceled.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def confirm
    @fields = %i[vehicle_type, carplate, studentid, name, department, permitstart, permitend]
    @permit = current_user.permits.build(permit_params)
    render :new and return unless @permit.valid?
  end

  def show
    @permits = Permit.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @permits = Permit.where(user_id: current_user).take
    respond_to do |format|
      if @permits.update(permit_params)
        format.html { redirect_to root_path}
        flash[:success] = "Permit successfully updated"
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def edit
    @permits = Permit.find(params[:id])
    #@permits = Permit.find_or_initialize_by(user_id: params[:id])
  end

  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_permit
    @permits = Permit.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def permit_params
    params.require(:permit).permit(:vehicle_type, :name, :studentid, :department, :carplate, :duration, :permitstart, :permitend)
  end
end
```

Route.db

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  resources :permits do
    collection do
      post :confirm
    end
  end
  resources :visitor_permits do
    collection do
      post :confirm
    end
  end
  resources :invoice
  resources :receipt
  resources :health_report

  root 'static_pages#home'


  get 'permitapplication' => 'permits#new'
  get 'viewpermit' =>'permits#show'
  get 'show_permit' =>'permits#index'
  get 'invoice' => 'permits#invoice'
  post 'createpermit' => 'permits#create'
  post 'permits' => 'permits#create'

  post 'createvpermit' => 'visitor_permits#create'
  post 'vpermits' => 'visitor_permits#create'
  get 'show_vpermit' =>'visitor_permits#index'
  get 'show_visitor_permit' =>'visitor_permits#show'
  get 'visitorpermit' => 'visitor_permits#new'

  get 'createinvoice' => 'invoice#new'
  post 'invoice' => 'invoice#create'

  get 'new_health_report' => 'health_report#new'

  get 'payment' =>'transaction#new'

  get 'homepage/index'

  get 'adminlogin' => 'admin_controller#index'

  get 'patrollogin' => 'patrol_officer#index'

  post 'citations' => 'citations#create'
  get 'new_citation' => 'citations#new'
  get 'unpaid_citations' => 'citations#list_all'
  get 'edit_Citation' => 'citations#edit'

  get 'contact'=> 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'about' => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'help' => 'static_pages#help'

  get 'signup' => 'users#new'
  post 'users' => 'users#create'

  get 'login' => 'sessions#new' #Page for a new session
  post 'login' => 'sessions#create' #Create a new session
  delete 'logout'=>'sessions#destroy' #Delete a session


  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Comment: Can you post the `routes` for invoice ?

Comment: I have updated my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that your `createinvoice` route is not setup to accept any extra parameter. default route should have generated something like `invoice/new`. So while sending `@permit` id in path you need something like:

```
redirect_to createinvoice_path(permit_id: @permits.id)
```

and in `invoice_controller` fetch `params[:permit_id]`

EDIT:
    I am not good at explaining but I will try.
your route path for invoice is `get createinvoice` so when someone visits `yourdomain.com/createinvoice` it will take to that page.
Notice that your route `get createinvoice` does not contain any placeholder for any params, something you see in rails default generated show page like `get users/:id` . If the route setup is like this then when we write `redirect_to users_path(@user)`, rails will take the `id` of `@user` and replace it in `url` and it will become like `users/3` when page renders if users id is 3 and in controller you can access that id by `params[:id]` . But in your case route is not setup to accept any params so rails is simply ignoring the `@permits` inside the `createinvoice_path` and you are getting error since there is no `id` is present in `params`.
What I suggested is `createinvoice_path(permit_id: @permits.id)` which will make the url as `createinvoice/?permit_id=3` if the id of permits is 3. So this will send the params as a query params like you see while you search in google. And you will get the `permit_id` in `params`.

Hope you got my point.

Comment: Thanks! It solved my problem, but I still not quite clear about how this solution works. Would you mind to explain to me in details?